# Upgrade Win 8.1 RTM Core OEM:NONSLP to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 RTM Core OEM:NONSLP (found this out vis the tool ShowKey Plus). Can I upgrade this to Windows 10 and how ? My laptop did get a "upgrade to Windows 10 button", which I missed on my workstation.

I did find out that it could be that a update offering this is missing from my system, but I can't find what update and the system itself isn't offering this choice.

Comment: Just accept and schedule the upgrade.  Be sure you have the required updates installed of the machine your asking about wasn't offered the update, or skip that step, and just use the MediaCreationTool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can upgrade, according to this article: http://www.computerworld.com/article/2899229/microsoft-reveals-who-gets-windows-10-and-how.html ("Upgrades will be possible from older versions, including the original 2009 edition, Windows 7 RTM (for "release to manufacturing"); Windows 8; and Windows 8.1 RTM. Those devices, however, will be upgradable only from installation media, like a DVD or USB drive, loaded with a disk image downloaded from Microsoft's servers as an .iso file.").

So, you need to secure installation media from Microsoft. You can do that here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/.

Comment: "Those devices, however, will be upgradable only from installation media" - This is false

Comment: That's just what was published on the upgrade matrix long ago. Fine if the situation has changed since then.

Comment: Changed with 1511